# How to get Object ID in MinIO

Tags: minio

I am currently making some reaching for the MinIO.  I wonder if there is the object ID concept in MinIO that we can identify the object uniquely.
or the only way is through the bucket name and file name to identify the stored object.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Object:
"""Object information."""

def __init__(self,  # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
             bucket_name,
             object_name,
             last_modified=None, etag=None,
             size=None, metadata=None,
             version_id=None, is_latest=None, storage_class=None,
             owner_id=None, owner_name=None, content_type=None,
             is_delete_marker=False):
    self._bucket_name = bucket_name
    self._object_name = object_name
    self._last_modified = last_modified
    self._etag = etag
    self._size = size
    self._metadata = metadata
    self._version_id = version_id
    self._is_latest = is_latest
    self._storage_class = storage_class
    self._owner_id = owner_id
    self._owner_name = owner_name
    self._content_type = content_type
    self._is_delete_marker = is_delete_marker**strong text**
```

https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/minio/datatypes.py

-First, sorry for my bad english-

I don't know what your client api is (maybe just mc?), But official github code can help you.

I find python api code at github. It has all attribute for minio object, But it has no object id in properties.

So, it doesn't have any way to search data with object id in python api, in my thoughts...

And only way to search object is using bucket name and object name as you write above.